# Vala: Pass String as Class

Tags: linux, class, ubuntu, gtk, vala

**Scenario:**
I have x number of classes. Lets say 10; Each class does different UI Functions. When a user loads a file, that extension tells the program the classname to load; but it's in the form of a string.

Is there anyway to pass a string off as a classname? Something to the effect of.

```
 var classname = "Booger";

 var nose = new classname(){ //classname really means "Booger"
 //Do Operation
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reflect a type by name using `var t = Type.from_name(classname);`, however, this works on *all* types, including enums and structs and it might be the type `Type.INVALID`. You should probably do some checks, like `t.is_a(typeof(MyParentClass))`.

You can then instantiate a copy using `var obj = Object.new(t);`. The whole thing would look like:

```
var classname = "Booger";
var t = Type.from_name(classname);
if (t.is_a(typeof(MyParentClass)))
  return Object.new(t);
else
  return null;
```

It's also worth noting that the run-time type names have the namespace prepended, so you might want to do `"MyNs" + classname`. You can check in either the generated C or doing `typeof(MyClass).name()`.

Comment: I gave this a shot, it's showing the proper C Chain.. But it gives an error about being a GObject, and when tested with "type.is_classed" it comes back false. This is the error i'm getting.

     (eStudio:21063): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

     ** (eStudio:21063): CRITICAL **: estudio_docview_source_Register_DocView: assertion `self != NULL' failed (estudio_docview_source_Register_DocView IS CORRECT)
     Segmentation fault

Comment: Does your parent class extend GLib.Object?

Comment: Yes, it does extend GLib.Object

Comment: Whatever I do it considers it a string and not a class. Even if it's assigned as an Object. It's considered a string.

Comment: But it passes the `is_a` test?

Comment: Wait, you correctly get a `Type`? Try adding a `stdout.printf("The type is %s and is classed? %s is instantiable? %s\n", t.name(), type.is_classed ().to_string (), type.is_instantiatable ().to_string ()));`. This type you get back passes the `is_a` test?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem as the OP in regards to getting an assertion error against null. If you take a look at the Glib documentation (in C) it mentions you have to register your class by actually specifying the class name first before you can actually use a string representation of your class name.

In other words you have to use your class first BEFORE you can instantiate a copy of your class with Glib.Type.from_name ("ClassName").

You can use your class first by instantiating a class instance or by getting type information for your class.

```
var type = typeof (MyClass);
var type_from_string = Type.from_name ("MyClass");
```

Furthermore, when you use Object.new to create a class there are two things you need to be aware of:

1) You need to cast the return value to get your specific class or base class.

```
var instance_of_my_class = Object.new (type) as MyClass;
```

2) Constructors for your class will no longer be called (I don't why). You will need to use the GObject style constructor inside your class:

```
construct {
    pizza = 5;
}
```